# mobaxterm doesn't correctly pass ctrl-shift-arrow sequences

Tags: terminal, xterm, linux-terminal, mobaxterm

MobaXterm doesn't correctly pass ctrl-shift-arrow sequences.
It doesn't work on emacs, and when I use `sed -n l`, I see it displays the escape sequence of the arrow key alone instead of the full sequence.

For example, ctrl-shift-right is passed as `^[OC` (which is the same as the escape sequence of the right key `^[[C`).

Any idea of how to solve this?
Note that ctrl-arrow key (without shift) and shift-arrow (without ctrl) pass correctly, and that the session terminal is set to `xterm`.

Answer (score -1):

"Correct" would be an appropriate term if there were a well-established standard for special keys.  There is none.

Mobaxterm is based on PuTTY (starting with its source-code), and adds **some** key-bindings to imitate xterm, but the set of key-bindings is not complete.